# Objective C - index of object from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array called "teams" and all items of class called "teamType". In my method, I want to check the index of object of "teamType" its index from "teams" array:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

teamType *te = [[teamType alloc]init];
//here I want to check te's index depending on the indexpath 


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[te Name] forKey:@"buttonSelected"];
}
```

Comment: teams[indexPath.row]

Comment: `int index = [teams indexOfObject:objTeamType];`

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati For that to work, the class needs to implement at least one method, no?  However I think he wants `teamType *te = teams[indexPath.row];`.

Comment: yes it worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
teamType *te = teams[indexPath.row];
```